# Server Error value cannot be null fileContents from FileResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i try sending to my view a FileResult the problem is everything work fine on localhost but when deploy in my server this is the error server show when i try to load the page where i display the FileResult. Is there somebody who happen to have this problem and solve it?

[image]

here is the controller

```
public FileResult PdfAlpha()
{
    int j = 0;
    int z = 0;
    var surnameList = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToList();
    string html = "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr width='220'><td valign='top'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";

    foreach(char header in surnameList)
    {
        string ch = header.ToString();
        j++;
        List<RssMasterModel> rssMasterModel = context.RssMasterModel.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.prenom) && w.isUser == 1 && w.prenom != null && w.isAncien.Equals(false) && w.nom.StartsWith(ch)).OrderBy(m => m.nom).ToList();
        if (rssMasterModel.Count > 0)
        {    
            foreach (RssMasterModel model in rssMasterModel)
            {
                if (j > 40)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    html += "</table></td>";
                    html += "<td valign='top'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
                }
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    html += "<tr height='5'><td align='center'><strong>" + ch + "</strong></td><td></td></tr>";
                }
                html += "<tr width='220' ><td width='170'>" + model.nom + ", " + model.prenom + "</td><td width='50'>" + model.phone + "</td></tr>";
                j++;
                z++;
            }
            z = 0;
        }
    }
    html += "</table></td></tr></table>";
    return new FileContentResult(CFunctions.ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape(html).Data, "application/pdf");
}
```

this is my view

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="loadImg"><div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajaxSpinner.gif")" /></div></div>
    <iframe src="@Url.Content("~/PhoneBook/PhonePDF/PdfAlpha")"
            style="width: 100%; height: 796px; " frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>

</div>
```

here the method ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape

```
public static ReturnValue ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape(string HtmlData)
{
    ReturnValue Result = new ReturnValue();
    try
    {
        HtmlToPdfConverter htpc = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
        htpc.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        htpc.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--margin-top 5 --header-spacing 0 --margin-left 5 --margin-right 0 --encoding UTF-8";
        Result.Data = htpc.GeneratePdf(HtmlData);
        Result.Success = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Result.Success = false;
        Result.Message = ex.Message;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking the count for rssMasterModel, do a null check. If the list is null and you try and get the count of it, it will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: are any exception appearing in logging or in the server event viewer? are you using the correct database connection string? are their any files to display?

Comment: well connection string is correct one since i use the same database in local to connect in server i ask the administrator to give full access on the account all other query work fine

Comment: @DarkVision are there files in the server to display?

Comment: the null check doesn't change nothing same result i put log on the server to check the list and its fine the count see value

Comment: CFunctions.ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape(html).Data this return byte array  its work in localhost

Comment: your `CFunctions.ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape(html)` method is failing.. could be a missing dll reference or something.. you must have a try/catch in there somewhere that return null if failing..

Comment: i will add some log and check what FileContentResult return

Comment: it's pretty clear that `CFunctions.ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape(html).Data` is null..   the `Data` part to be more specific..

Comment: is `ConvertHtmlToPdfLandscape` something you wrote or part of a third party library?  can you post the code for this function?

Comment: yeah your right problem with this method when using on deploy server weird that work in local i use nReco html to pdf converter i will edit post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found my problem
the different between my developement environnement and the server is i need to install **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for VS2013**. Hope this help somebody who has the same problem i had.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have all the references you need. I had this error and the problem was  I was missing `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`.